# Best way to use a large image (8000x5000 at 20mb) in android using opengl-es

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am been doing some research lately and haven't come by a good answer, what I want to do is display a very large image 8000x5000 at 20mb in my application as a background (it is a minigame) the reasoning for the large image is that the user can zoom so we want to keep that high detail at maximum zoom. However this is a very large file and will clog up a lot of the allowed memory any idea's on how to implement this in to an Android application without killing the memory limit ?

Thank you in advance for the time taken to read/assist with this.

Comment: When in full view, display a lower quality version of the full image. If they zoom, figure out the coordinates and crop off of the 'original' image, and display a lower quality version of the crop. This way, you have a very minimal foot-print in memory. You can just have the original 20mb image saved on disk, but never fully in memory. Just take pieces that you need. Just a thought.

Comment: @xil3 lower quality version if the crop? how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use different images for different zoom levels.

Load the lower resolution image when there is no zoom in.

As the user zooms in, load the next level zoom image, but not the whole image, load only the region he wants. Using [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) you can load only a part of the image.

Comment: Hmm this method sounds promising will this allow for a smooth zoom or will it get choppy when you zoom due to loading and unloading textures?

Comment: @Dev-Mev Unfortunately it depends on the device (and the frequency the user is expected to zoom in and out or scroll over the image). There are ways to speed it up, though. For example, predicting what will be the next possible loads, preloading the neighbour regions of the image and the region of the next level image corresponding to the actual showed region.

Comment: @Dev-Mev Or look at how the photograpy viewers work. Firt show a region of the actual loaded texture resized to fill the screen (already loaded) so it takes no time, but it has low quality. Meanwhile, load the proper resolution texture and when its loaded, change the low quality image for the new one.

Comment: Will do thank you for the advice Evans, also would tiling the map with smaller images be a much memory less solution as opposed to the larger image.

Comment: @Dev-Mev Check this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050(VS.95).aspx Not related to android, but the basics are the same. Look at the image section "Creating a Deep Zoom Image". With tiling you are always loading an image of 256x256 (or your custom tile size), from a different image depending on the zoom level. With a large image, eventually you will need to load it full and break the memory limits.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to get around this issue is to do something like Google's mapping and use tiles.  You'll need a much lower resolution image for the lowest zoom level, then have tiles for each subsequent zoom level and draw whatever tiles the user would be able to see when they are zoomed in.

Unfortunately for this to be fast on zoom you'll need to load the different tiles into memory ahead of time which *might* take a similar amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it will only be 20 MB (MB = mega byte, mb = milli-bit)  I fyou have more than one byte per pixel it can be much higher.

What you can do is to have low resolution copies for different depths of zoom, broken up into tiles.  This way you only need tiles of about the size of your screen loaded at a time, i.e. with overlap this might be double the screen size.